# iptables to allow only ssh and https

Tags: linux, ssh, iptables, firewall, https

I'm trying to configure the iptables on my device in order to allow only **SSH** and **HTTPS** traffic. In particular, the HTTPS protocol is used to call some **REST API** toward a remote server **from a java client.**

This is my iptables:

```
iptables -F

iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP

#SSH
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 22 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

#DNS
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT

#HTTPS
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 443 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
```

Everything works as expected, except for HTTPS traffic, which is blocked by iptables.

What i made wrong?

Comment: Blocked in or blocked out? The sport of an outbound connection will almost certainly not be 443.

Comment: Do yourself a favor: 1. Don't write stateless firewalls. 2. If you don't know how to write a firewall from scratch, get a tool to generate it for you.

Comment: Should be OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 443 and INPUT -p tcp --sport 443 if you trigger some remote API from that machine.

Answer (score 7):

Do not block all the outbound rule, it will not choose port 443 as a source to get data from other server. And I think blocking inbound rules are pretty enough to ensure your server security. Rest is all Good. You can use below rules if you want.

```
iptables -F
iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -j DROP
```

Comment: This line is what you're missing OP:

iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT